# simultaneous equations with 3 variables

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have the following 3 equations and I need to find out if they are consistent, inconsistent or dependent using the substitute method.  I am using a textbook that wants you to use the substitution method so please do not offer an alternative or better method:

${5x -y = 3}$

${3x + y = 11}$

${y - 2z = -3}$

Using the 3rd equation, I can work out what y is:

${y = 2z - 3}$

if I then plug in y to the bottom equation I get:

${(2z -3) - 2z = - 3}$

So to me, this would equal:

0 - 3 = -3

So I would say the systems are dependent but according to the textbook, the systems are consistent and indeed the following 3 variables have the following results:

${{x = {7\over 4}}, {y = {23\over4}}, {z = {35\over8}}}$

I have no idea how these values are obtained due to my substitutions.

Answer (score 0):

You just showed that 3rd equation is dependend with itself. You need to put $y=2z-3$ into first or second equation.